# Formatting date - Cognos Report Studio

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-bi

In Cognos Reporting Studio I have a data item coming in that is a string representation of a date (varchar2). Example: 20230714

I need to display it in a column as a date in the format 'YYYY/MM/DD' without a timestamp. Example: 2023/07/14

I have used the cast function in the data item expression to convert it from a varchar to a date:
cast([X].[Y].[Z], date)

The column is now displaying as a date in a 'Month Date, Year' format. Example: July 14, 2023

To change it to my desired format, I went to the column -> Properties -> Data -> Data Format. I believe there is then supposed to be a 'Date' type option, where I can then specify a pattern, but I only see 'Default' and 'Text'. Is this option no longer there?

So for now I have selected Text -> Pattern and applied 'yyyy/MM/dd'

However my output is still showing in the July 14, 2023 format. Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Is there maybe another function I can use in the expression itself?

Comment: I think you have left out a critical piece of information.  Vocabulary is important when working with Cognos.  Words actually do mean things.  "The column is displaying..."  Where?  Based on what you describe, I suspect this is not a column at all.  At the top of the Properties pane, look at the name of the object you have selected.  Is it a crosstab node member?

Comment: Report Studio?  So is this `cognos-10`?